# laravel 5.3: setup virtual host. Getting Apache 404 error

Tags: apache, laravel, ubuntu, http-status-code-404, virtualhost

I want to setup a virtual host in my localhost, so I can access my Laravel app like this: `demo.example.com`. I have added a custom `conf` file: `etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf` with the following contents:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin username@gmail.com

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAlias demo.example.com
    ServerAlias www.demo.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/example/public>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Contents from `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       username-pc
127.0.0.1       example.com
127.0.0.1       www.example.com
127.0.0.1       http://exaple.com
127.0.0.1       demo.example.com
```

With the above settings if I access the url `demo.example.com` it works. But if I try to access other routes like `demo.example.com/login` I get **apache 404** error: **The requested URL /login was not found on this server. How do I fix this?**

Note that this is not laravel's **NotFoundHttpException**.

Answer (score 0):

place this under your directory tag

```
<Directory /var/www/example/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Still I get the same error: `The requested URL /login was not found on this server.`

Comment: did you enable mod rewrite module?, and I have also updated the answer try it now